# Convert SQL to LINQ, group by inner table

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql

Can someone please help to convert this to linq?

```
SELECT x.contentobjectid, Min(x.city) as city, temp.startdate
from calendarentry as x
    inner join (select contentobjectid, startdate from calendarentry where startdate > getdate() group by contentobjectid, startdate) as temp
    on temp.contentobjectid = x.contentobjectid
group by x.contentobjectid, temp.startdate
```

im using Entity framework

thanks

Comment: what are you using, EF, EF4, L2S, etc? the linq statement will be different based on the framework used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your db schema its hard to really get this right, but try what I've written as a starting point. Also, I highly recommend downloading LINQPad, and pay the 30 bucks for the intellisense support!

```
var result = (
from c1 in calendarentry
let grp = (from c2 in calendarentry
             where c2.contentobjectid = c1.contentopjectid &&
                   c2.startdate > DateTime.Now
             group c2 by new { contentobjectid = c2.contentobjectid, startdate = c2.startdate } into g
             select g)
select new {
         contentobjectid = c1.contentobjectid, 
         city = c1.Min(x => x.city),
         startdate = grp.startDate
       });
```